# Limiting the inputs to a constructor while keeping constructor code minimal

Tags: java, constructor

Well, I was told that I have to create a money class that accepts currency and value. The value should be stored as 2 integers, one representing the dollar value, then the other one in cents.

****It should accept the decimal value precise to two (2) decimal places. ****

So I suppose I have to limit the cents value so that it should accept only 1 to 2 digit integers. Now, my problem is, my mentor told me that it is bad practice to do other stuff inside the constructor. How am I supposed to limit the input then if I'm not allowed to do anything with the constructor other than:

```
public class Money {
    Currency currency;
    int dollar;
    int cents;

    public Money(Currency currency, int dollar, int cents) {
        super();
        this.currency = currency;
        this.dollar = dollar;
        this.cents = cents;
    }
    ..... other code.....
}
```

Any other ideas on how I am supposed to implement what was instructed of me? Why is it bad practice and is there a way to define constraints without being guilty of this bad practice???

Comment: You shouldn't keep dollars and cents separate. Just keep track of the number of cents, and divide by 100. And use `BigInteger`, not `int`.

Besides, in other currencies, the values are not called dollars and cents.

See http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html

Comment: @황현정: Using 32-bit integers (signed or not) to represent money is nearly always a code smell.  There are a **lot** of broken applications out there where that mistake was made that more or less "work" as of now but should hyper-inflation happen (it already happened to a lot of countries and it may happen again), all these applications would break.  Use either 64-bit primitives (signed or not) or *BigInteger*.

Comment: But BigInteger consumes too much memory especially when used in loops and stuff, as I have read in Effective Java, besides, it was in the specs that my mentor handed to me, so I have to follow instructions or I'm doomed! haha.. What I'm thinking is just to convert the dollar to cents and cents to dollar instead of using Big Integer. :D

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarstom Yeah, I was wondering about the dollar and cents thing, but I guess he meant something like, whole part(dolla), and fractional part(cents), otherwise, it wouldn't make sense to add currency into the constraints.

Comment: Tell the teacher that someone on the internet said that he is teaching awful practices when he is demanding that you use `int` for monetary values. Link him here.

Don't forget to read the excellent example in Martin Fowler's article: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is validating the inputs to the constructor.  Although in general "other stuff" in a constructor is not optimal, doing input verification code there is certainly warranted.  Something like the following is a *good* pattern IMO:

```
public Money(Currency currency, int dollar, int cents) {
    this.currency = currency;
    this.dollar = dollar;
    // validate that cents is 0 to 99
    if (cents < 0 || cents > 99) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid cents value: " + cents);
    }
    this.cents = cents;
}
```

Btw, there is no point in calling `super()` at the front of your constructor unless.  The Java language calls the base class constructor automagically under the covers.

Comment: If the instructor really doesn't want anything in the constructor, you could put your verification in a private method and just throw the IllegalArgumentException from the constructor as well.

Comment: You could simpler just say `0 <= cents && cents < 100`, to prevent negative values and avoid confusing division.

Comment: But you kept the confusing division? Simpler to just say `cents > 99` than `cents / 100 > 0`.

Comment: It should be `cents > 99`, not `cents > 100`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common reason people give for this is that the constructor should be as fast as possible to eliminate any concurrency issues, and foolproof because constructors are a bit harder to diagnose.

In your case, simple numeric validation is just fine.

However, as Marcello said, you might consider writing validation functions and calling them from the constructor, to ensure consistency.

Answer (score 0):

First off I don't think it is a bad practice to validate and throw an exception if you get an invalid object by using the constructor.
That said, looking at your requirement,It might be good enough to round the cents. Lastly you can look at other Money implementations e.g. [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13)

Answer (score -1):

It is bad pratice to add code inside the Constructor,your mentor is right.
But adding methods call ,is not.

So you can just encapsulate the operations that will limit the input in another method and call it right after the super.

But,the best pratice in my opinion,is to deal with the input limitation before passing it to the constructor.

Parse the input in a separated class,or in the code behind the interface class.
Avoid using code operation into a class that is representing a Model of something,in this case, your "Money Model"

Why it is bad pratice ?

In Object Orientation you have to write classes so that they dont execute more operations that they would have to know. In this case,your class is representing a model of an object,money. Why would a model need to,by itself, parse the value passed to its contructor ?
Got it ? The best pratice,is to pass the values for the constructor,already parsed and limited,so that the class will only need to store this values.

For example,lets say yesterday your constraints change,all you would have to do,is changing the parsing part,instead of having to write code inside the Money class.

Other example,someone will have to use your money class,but it will have its own constraints,all he have to do is using his parsing class,instead of changing yours inside the money class
Hope it helps.

Comment: I really disagree with the idea of doing "input limitation" outside of the class. If the class is expecting that cents < 100 then it should verify it.  Otherwise it is assuming that the inputs are correct.  This seems reckless.

Comment: And I _really_ take issue with the following statement.  "The best practice, is to pass the values for the constructor,already parsed and limited,so that the class will only need to store this values."   If you are talking about web presentation objects or database objects then maybe this is true but it is certainly not universal.

Comment: In my opinion that are classes that represent a Model,and classes that realize operations. Thats how i see the whole thing,ofc a model can realize operations over its content,like converting and returning a value. But,for sure,sanitizing the input outside the class still the best pratice.

Comment: You don't have to be that harsh and give him a vote down.. T_T Geez.. I feel sorry for asking this question already

Comment: Its ok,Gray is probably a Great Programmer.
I will review my point of view about the whole thing.
Good to know you solved your problem,thats what the community is for,@Gray is just doing his job.
See you

Comment: @황현정 Actually that is encouraged by StackOverflow. Quote: Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. And i absolutely agree with Gray, a class (unless its just a dumb helper) should almost never expect that input is clean. Once your applications get bigger bugs can creep in that are hard to debug. Check your input and fail fast with a clear message.

Answer (score -1):

I would throw an `ExceptionInInitializerError` if the cents value is greater than 100.  Either that, or divide by 100 and add the quotient to the dollars and the remainder to the cents.  Normalizing and validating your constructor arguments is not a bad practice.

Comment: No, you should not throw an `Error` for anything less than VM bugs, you should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.